# How to populate text field in a shapefile table by 0 length string using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile

Experiment:

Original table:

[image]

Field calculator expression applied to TXTfield:

```
“”
```

Add numeric field:

[image]

Field calculator expression applied to numField:

```
len( [TXTfield])
```

Result:

[image]

Note:

1. arcpy.da.searchCursor also reports 1 character long string in
   TXTfield
2. ArcView 3 reports zero length string

Question:

What is going on?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: It's best to leave your question here, even though it is a duplicate.  That way it is another signpost to the answer.  Since it took me a while to find the duplicate your question will provide more keywords to make that easier next time.